# stacked bartplot and line on the same chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Consider the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dfa = pd.DataFrame({'time' : [pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2021-01-03'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2021-01-03'),
                             ],
                   'group' : ['a','b','a','b','a','b'],
                   'value' : [1,2,3,2,5,5]})

dfa
Out[266]: 
        time group  value
0 2021-01-01  a     1    
1 2021-01-01  b     2    
2 2021-01-02  a     3    
3 2021-01-02  b     2    
4 2021-01-03  a     5    
5 2021-01-03  b     5  

dli = pd.DataFrame({'time' :[pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2021-01-03')],
                    'value' : [100,200,50]})

dli
Out[267]: 
        time  value
0 2021-01-01  100  
1 2021-01-02  200  
2 2021-01-03  50
```

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart using `dfa` with plot a line chart on top of it using `dli`. The issue is that my code below makes the bar plot disappear (although the charts plotted individually work).

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

dfa.set_index(['time','group']).unstack().plot.bar(stacked = True, ax = ax1)
dli.set_index('time').plot(ax = ax2, color = 'red',
                           linewidth = 4, secondary_y = True)
```

[image]

Can you see what the issue is? For instance, the single line works

```
dfa.set_index(['time','group']).unstack().plot.bar(stacked = True)
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: pandas barplot plots against the range index, then rename the ticks.

Comment: The issue is with the date as the index with `bar` and `line` plots treating them differently. My guess is `line` assumes its numeric while `bar` treats it basically as a string to delineate categories. If you make them both strings, `dfa['time'] = dfa['time'].astype(str)` then there wont be an issue, though maybe spacing will be odd if dates are differently spaced

Comment: thanks! can you please post a solution then?

Comment: the thing is that I would like to retain the ability to use `mdates.MonthLocator()` at some point to have x labels that make sense. Converting to strings will lose that ability. I hope there is a solution that addresses that

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ in which case, I think you need to plot with `plt.bar`. Either with `bottom` argument or with `cumsum()` on the data.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks! would you mind posting a solution based on my example then? I think this will be very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
# plot data
d = dfa.set_index(['time','group']).unstack().cumsum(1)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for c in d.columns[::-1]:
    ax.bar(d.index, d[c], label=c)
ax.legend()

ax1 = ax.twinx()

ax1.plot(dli['time'], dli['value'], color='r', label='value')
ax1.legend(loc='upper right')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks! I am just a bit confused by the date labels on the x axis?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I believe it's `MM:DD HH`.

Comment: just a follow up if you have some time. How would you only show the dates labels, say, every 2 days?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to get what you want. I was not able to get the right y-axis to be red and have a label for some reason, my code to attempt this are the 2nd/3rd lines of code under the line chart plot section.

```
# Create figure and axes
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (12, 10))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# Create x, y1, y2
x = dfa['time']
y1 = dfa.set_index(['time','group']).unstack()
y2 = dli['value']
         
# Plot stacked bar chart (left y-axis)
y1.plot.bar(stacked = True, ax = ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel('Date', fontsize = 14)
ax1.set_xticklabels(('2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03'), rotation = 0)
ax1.set_ylabel('Value (Groups a & b)', color = 'orange', fontsize = 14)
ax1.tick_params(axis = 'y', rotation = 0, labelcolor = 'blue' )
ax1.legend(title='')#set bar chart legend title to blank

# Plot line chart (right y-axis)
y2.plot(secondary_y = True, color = 'red', linewidth = 4, label = 'value (no group)')
ax2.set_ylabel('Value (No Group)', color = 'red', fontsize = 14)
ax2.tick_params(axis = 'y', rotation = 0, labelcolor = 'red' )

# Show line chart legend
plt.legend()

plt.show();
```

[Combo stacked bar chart and line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ5YU.png)